# Is it possible to define routes.yaml defaults/requirements globally?

Tags: symfony, symfony6

In Symfony 6 routes.yaml I have:

```
somepage1:
  path: /{_locale}/somepage1
  controller: App\Controller\PageController::somepage1
  defaults:
    _locale: en
  requirements:
    _locale: en|fr|de

somepage2:
  path: /{_locale}/somepage2
  controller: App\Controller\PageController::somepage2
  defaults:
    _locale: en
  requirements:
    _locale: en|fr|de
```

As there will be many routes, is it possible to define the defaults and requirements more globally, so that they get applied to all URLs that use the _locale variable? This is to avoid entering this for all the routes when new languages are added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, everything is written here.
https://symfony.com/doc/6.2/the-fast-track/en/28-intl.html

You need to create a new parameter:
`app.supported_locales: 'en|fr|de'`

---

If above solution doesn't work for you, then you need to use `RequestListener` to check for supported locales

Comment: Thanks! I see it. Do you know how to call this new parameter in the routes.yaml in the requirements part?

Comment: Found it: '%app.supported_locales%'

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, but I see you already solved your problem :)